# Why does `RtlGetFullPathName_U` look different in ntdll.dll and reactos' docs?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, ntdll

I'm hooking an udocumented Windows API function `RtlGetFullPathName_U` (residing in ntdll.dll), to detect process injections in my game. However, the function type looks different when looking at the function in IDA, and when looking at the function through the only info I could find about the function (from ReactOS's docs).

When looking in IDA:

[image]

The file analyzed above is `ntdll.dll` found through x32dbg:

[image]

When looking in ReactOS' [docs](https://doxygen.reactos.org/df/d1a/RtlGetFullPathName__U_8c_source.html#l00001), I see `RtlGetFullPathName_U` looks like this:

```
ULONG
 NTAPI
 RtlGetFullPathName_U(
     IN PCWSTR FileName,
     IN ULONG Size,
     IN PWSTR Buffer,
     OUT PWSTR *ShortName
 );
```

Using ReactOS' version of `RtlGetFullPathName_U` works when I hook, but I notice a difference in amount of parameters, why is that? I mean my approach would normally be to see the exported functions through IDA, not through ReactOS' documentation.

A last question; are there other relevant functions I could hook to detect process injections? Besides LoadLibraryA/W/Ex?

Comment: *ReactOS* definitions is correct. and it does not contradict to what you see in disasm

Comment: Wait, why does it not contradict?

Comment: where you view contradict in asm code ? exactly same

Comment: I see 4 parameters vs. 5 parameters. Is it just me? IDA: void*, int, int, int, int, int ReactOS: PCWSTR, ULONG, PWSTR, PWSTR

Comment: `__thiscall` calling convention seems wrong, should be `__stdcall`. Main difference: `__thiscall` uses `ECX` register for passing `this` pointer.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed calling convention was wrong too. But the parameters themselves are also integers, not PCWSTR, ULONG, PWSTR, PWSTR. What would one do if they didn't have access to ReactOS' documentation?

Comment: Because P(C)WSTR is pointer, so IDA shows this as int. Why you need documentation, if you have decompiled function?

Comment: I'm confused because they show different parameters and different amounts of parameters.

Comment: in **asm** code no any contradict with *h* file definition. ida of course wrong show. and any decompiler can not know type of argumets.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the disassembly, the function uses `push ecx` early on, followed by saving the address of the just-pushed value in `eax`. The address in `eax` is then pushed onto the stack as an argument for the next function.
So what you read in the decompiler output is not technically wrong: it stores the value of ecx in a local variable and then passes the address of that local variable to `RtlGetFullPathName_UEx`.
To capture this, IDA assumes that the value passed to the function in `ecx` might matter and marks it as a parameter.

However, most likely, the real purpose of the `push ecx` instruction here is not to save the value of `ecx`, but simply to reserve four bytes on the stack for a local variable (a more common idiom for which would be `sub esp, 4`). Using `push` is an optimization.

To confirm this definitively, you would have to analyze the called function, `RtlGetFullPathName_UEx`, and see whether it ever reads the contents of the memory pointed to by its last parameter. If, as I strongly suspect, it does not, and this parameter is only used for output, then the value in the caller can simply be considered uninitialized.

After you've confirmed this (or if for some other reason, e.g. trusting ReactOS's declaration, you believe this is the case), you can modify the function prototype to use `__stdcall` and remove the `void *this` parameter in IDA, and it will show it as what it (probably) is: passing a pointer to an uninitialized local variable.